# NoReverseMatch at /rubies/users/1/: Reverse for 'story' with arguments '(1, '')' not found

Tags: django

> NoReverseMatch at /rubies/users/1/
>
> Reverse for 'story' with arguments '(1, '')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['rubies/users/(?P[0-9]+)/stories/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

I faced the same problem with my story page, where the error

> Reverse for 'user' with arguments '(1, '')' not found

came up. Gladly, somebody helped me solve that problem. However, I cannot manage to find the solution to this one, even though it's practically the same.

**user.html**

```
{% extends "rubies/base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
        Name: {{ user.username }}
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <ul>
            Stories:
            {% if story_id %}
                {% for story in user.story.all %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{% url 'rubies:story' user.id story.id %}">{{ story.title }}</a>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {% if current_user == story.author.id %}
                    <h2 class="bg-warning">You have not written any stories yet.</h2>
                    <a href="{% url 'rubies:story' user.id story.id %}">
                        <span class="fas fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </a>
                {% else %}
                    <h2 class="bg-warning"> {{ story.author.username }} has not written any stories yet. </h2>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**user.view**

```
def user_view(request, user_id):
if user_id is not None:
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
else:
    user = User()

context = {
    'user_id': user_id,
    'name': user.name,
    'surname': user.surname,
    'username': user.username,
    'password': user.password,
    'email': user.email
    }
return render(request, 'rubies/user.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from rubies import views
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'rubies'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index_view, name='index'),
    path('register/', views.register_view, name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path('users/<int:user_id>/', views.user_view, name='user'),
    path('users/<int:user_id>/stories/<int:story_id>/', views.story_view, name='story'),
    path('users/<int:user_id>/new_story/', views.story_view, name='new_story'),
]
```

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you problem is probably here:

## code in here runs if there is a story_id

```
<ul>
        Stories:
        {% if story_id %} 
           ....
```

## code in here runs if there is NOT a story_id

```
        {% else %}
                <a href="{% url 'rubies:story' user.id story.id %}">
                    <span class="fas fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span>

        {% endif %}
    </ul>
```

in the else you try to create a url with a **story.id** but it is probably not there? Just following the logic in your template